# javascript redirect sends X-Requested-With header in opera

Tags: javascript, http-headers, opera, window.location

Why all methods of change url in opera send header [X-Requested-With] => XMLHttpRequest ?

I was checking

```
window.location = url
window.open(url,'_self')
window.location.replace(url)
```

How can I change url in opera without sending this header?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see that in the network panel. How did you find that header?

Comment: Can you specify which version / OS you are using?

Comment: I solved problem... I have bug that creating ajax request that started before this changing of url in contrast to the other browsers. 

Thanks for helping